# Jquery DataTables - trigger show all entries

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I would like to know if there is a function which can expand an entire Datatable. I don't mean to show all rows by default, but to switch from, for example, show 50 rows to show all rows (without having the user click the dropdown).

This is the kind of thing I am looking for:

```
var my_table = $('#my_table').DataTable()
my_table
    .rows(all) // the part I am unsure about!
    .draw()
```

Is there a way to do this? If not, I will have to simulate clicks with jquery

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found an answer on the [datatables reference](https://datatables.net/reference/api/page.len()).

You must set the page dynamically with a length of `-1`

```
var my_table = $('#my_table').DataTable()
my_table
    .page.len(-1) // set the length to -1
    .draw()
```